# access the SP2013 Site Settings->Master Page/Navigation settings etc using CSOM (client side object model)

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, csom

I want to access the SharePoint 2013 Site Settings → Master Page/Navigation settings etc. using CSOM (Client-Side Object Model) from JavaScript or REST service or Webservice which I can call from Javascript. Can I get the pointer if such API/objects are available for SharePoint 2013?

To be more specific: I want to access and **change the Site Setting → Navigation (under look and Feel) → Global and Current Navigation to "Structural Navigation" instead of "Managed Navigation". I want to achieve this using CSOM (Javascript / REST / Web Service).** I don't want to use server side object model.

Comment: I think this is something closest you can get from Client Object Model: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2013-Assign-new-5c19062b . I expect, that it should be possible to do from javascript as well. If you can specify your problem in more details, maybe i will be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marek Kembrowski !!!
Let me explain my problem in detail:

I want to access and change the Site Setting--> Navigation (under look and Feel)--> Global and Current Navigation to "Structural Navigation" instead of "Managed Navigation".
I want to achieve this using CSOM (Javascript / REST/WebSErvice). I dont have any option to use server side or managed object model.

I hope this might have give you a closer look to actual requirement.
Thanks again!!!
nks

Comment: In this case I don't know any way to achieve this (and I think there isn't any using Javascript/Webservices).

Answer (score 1):

**Perfectly working script for setting Master Page:**

$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.cmdSet').click(function () {

```
    var scriptBase = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/";

    $.getScript(scriptBase + "sp.runtime.js", function () {

        $.getScript(scriptBase + "sp.js", function () {

            $.getScript(scriptBase + "sp.core.js", sharePointReady);

        });
    });

});
```

});

```
// create page-level variables to hold client context and web
var context;
var web;
var masterurl;
var site;
function sharePointReady() {

// assign values to page-level variables
context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
web = context.get_web();

// provide CSOM with instructions to load info about current web


context.load(web, 'ServerRelativeUrl');
web.set_customMasterUrl(L_Menu_BaseUrl + '/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master');
web.set_masterUrl(L_Menu_BaseUrl + '/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master');
web.update();

context.executeQueryAsync(function () {

    alert("Starting Master Page Setting......");
    masterurl = web.get_serverRelativeUrl() + "/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master";
    alert(masterurl);
    alert("Master Page is Set Successfully!!!");

}, function (sender, args) {

    alert("Error: " + args.get_message());

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013 was introduced a new [SP.Publishing.Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj607195(v=office.15).aspx) namespace (part of SharePoint [Publishing JavaScript Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj607192(v=office.15).aspx)). 
In particular [WebNavigationSettings class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj994643(v=office.15).aspx) that is intended for managing the navigation settings for a publishing site.

The following example demonstrate how to set Global Navigation to display `Structural Navigation`:

```
function configureNavigation()
{
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();         
   var web = ctx.get_web();
   var webNavSettings = new SP.Publishing.Navigation.WebNavigationSettings(ctx,web);

   var navigation = webNavSettings.get_globalNavigation();
   navigation.set_source(SP.Publishing.Navigation.StandardNavigationSource.portalProvider); //set to Structural Navigation   
   webNavSettings.update();

   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
            console.log("Navigation settings have been updated successfully");  
        },function(sender,args){    
            console.log(args.get_message());
        });
}
```

Key points:

- [SP.Publishing.Navigation.StandardNavigationSource enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj994650%28v=office.15%29.aspx) identifies the three enumeration choices displayed on the `AreaNavigationSettings.aspx` control pan

Usage

```
var scriptBase = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/";   
$.when(
    $.getScript( scriptBase + "sp.js" ),
    $.getScript( scriptBase + "sp.publishing.js" ),
    $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
        $( deferred.resolve );
    })
).done(function(){
     configureNavigation();    
});
```